# Send SharePoint Alert to Public Folder in Exchange

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server, directory, public, alerts

I created a list and setup alerts that send to several individuals when a new item is added to the list.  However, I have one additional requirement to have an alert email sent to a Public Folder in Exchange.

The folder is setup with an email address, VSrequest@domain.com, but when I try to add that address into the "Send Alerts To" field (when creating a new alert), SharePoint returns an error: "No Exact match was found."

I thought about setting up the alert in a custom workflow through SharePoint designer, but is there a way to easily reuse the existing Alert Email as a template for the body of the custom alert?

Any other ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send an alert to a regular email address (or mailbox) because it isn't associated with a user/group. If it isn't associated with a user/group then it can't have permissions to any list or list items in SharePoint. Finally, if it doesn't have permissions then it can't receive an alert (or that would be a pretty big security hole).

Probably the easiest method is what you mention: using a custom SharePoint designer workflow. It isn't going to be 100% the same but you can just copy the HTML from a previous alert and then try to fill in the data as much as you can in the workflow. ([see here for an article describing almost exactly what you want](http://unitedsupplyco.sharepointsite.net/publicfacing/bensblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=49)).

Comment: Thanks!  I had originally tried copying the HTML out of the original Alert and pasted that into the workflow's email but that was gross.  That article is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen you can't setup an alert against a random email address - it has to be against a user (who has an email address).

So one option would be to create a domain user for VSrequest@domain.com - ensure they are in SharePoints user list (Site Settings > Users and Groups > All Users) then you will be able to setup the alert for that user which will go to that email address.

Other options include workflow as Kit mentions, Event Receivers or 3rd party software.

Comment: This would work as well.  I'm trying to avoid having our domain admins step into the project.  Appreciate the response though!